# c# data table merge and bind the result

Tags: c#, oracle

I am trying to merge two DataTables.

```
merg1 = db.Copy();
merg1.Merge(dbdataset2);
BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
bSource.DataSource = merg1;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;
```

**Result**
[image]

I want to add the merged data to the existing rows, rather than adding new rows and empty cells.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# merge data table issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38149402/c-sharp-merge-data-table-issues)

Comment: You shouldn't have asked a duplicate question. Others should refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38149402/c-sharp-merge-data-table-issues